# Equivalence of two statements in a field.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

I need to prove the following in order to prove something interesting about generalized quaternions:

Let $K$ be a field and suppose $a \neq 0, b \neq 0$ are elements of $K$. Then the following are equivalent:

1. For every $x, y, z, w \in K$, $x^2-y^2a-z^2b+w^2ab=0$ implies $x=y=z=w=0$.
2. For every $x, y, z \in K$, $x^2-ay^2-bz^2=0$ implies $x=y=z=0$

Of course $1$ implies $2$. I am having trouble on proving the converse.

Comment: Is there a reason you think it is true? If not, better to ask us to prove or disprove...

Comment: http://www.isibang.ac.in/~sury/vivekmukundan.pdf example $(i)$ on page $2$ makes me believe it's true